# Implement "isTyping" indicator in one-on-one chat with ionic and firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

I want to indicate to a user when another user is typing on a chat just the way WhatsApp does it. I'm using firebase real-time database and below is my database structure.[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3fuO.png)

Comment: can you also share your app relevant code as well as details around if structure used in firebase?

Comment: `getMatchMessages() {
    let temp;
    this.matchChats.child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).child(this.match.uid).on('value', (snapshot) => {
      this.matchMessages = [];
      temp = snapshot.val();
      console.log(temp)
      for (var tempkey in temp) {
        this.matchMessages.push(temp[tempkey]);
      }
      this.events.publish('newMessage');
    })
  }`

Comment: I haven't tried any if structure to implement this @SergeyRudenko

Comment: Welcome to SO. For us to help you, we would need to see your Firebase structure and what code you've attempted. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It’s also a good idea to include code and structures as text, not links and images. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)